# How can I read html with some rows with only one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the following table:

http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

In order to do this I am triying with the following code:

```
pd.read_html('http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html', skiprows=2, encoding="utf-8")[0]
```

The problem is that if I use skiprows the first two columns are skipped, but pick 3 columns as a header, and the other problem is that the header is multiple times on the table.

So how can read this, avoiding, the multiple headers, and columns with only one row?

Thanks

Comment: Try reading it using `Pandas's read_html`. More Info at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: I was using read_html, but I copied another trie. I updated the question.

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: I want to get only a table with the code, and browser icon representation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_html('http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html',encoding="utf-8")[0]
df.columns = [i[2] for i in df.columns]
```

Now if you print `df`, it looks like this

```
                     №                                               Code           Browser  ...               DCM              KDDI                  CLDR Short Name
0                    1                                            U+1F600                 �  ...                 —                 —                    grinning face
1                    2                                            U+1F603                 �  ...               NaN               NaN      grinning face with big eyes
2                    3                                            U+1F604                 �  ...                 —                 —  grinning face with smiling eyes
3                    4                                            U+1F601                 �  ...               NaN               NaN   beaming face with smiling eyes
4                    5                                            U+1F606                 �  ...               NaN                 —          grinning squinting face
...                ...                                                ...               ...  ...               ...               ...                              ...
2063  subdivision-flag                                   subdivision-flag  subdivision-flag  ...  subdivision-flag  subdivision-flag                 subdivision-flag
2064                 №                                               Code           Browser  ...               DCM              KDDI                  CLDR Short Name
2065              1814  U+1F3F4 U+E0067 U+E0062 U+E0065 U+E006E U+E006...           �������        ...                 —                 —                    flag: England
2066              1815  U+1F3F4 U+E0067 U+E0062 U+E0073 U+E0063 U+E007...           �������        ...                 —                 —                   flag: Scotland
2067              1816  U+1F3F4 U+E0067 U+E0062 U+E0077 U+E006C U+E007...           �������        ...                 —                 —                      flag: Wales

[2068 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: this dosen't work, you are picking the rows with only one column.

Comment: I'm picking all the rows and columns. You can see that at the end - `2068 rows x 15 columns`